# DbUpdateException on SaveChanges keeps throwing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I encounter weird exceptions while developping Asp.Net Mvc 5 using Entity Framework 6.0 database-first to access data.

First, when I try to delete a record, a DbUpdateException is thrown on SaveChanges :

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "ForeignKeyName". 
(...)
The statement has been terminated.
```

This exception is then caught by our ExceptionFilter :

```
public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    // Opening popup
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
}
```

Up to now, everything is fine. However, if after that the SavesChanges method is called again to update another entity, the same exception keeps throwing.

I taught it was related to the debug mode (cf post [Exception seems to be thrown repeatedly when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616714/exception-seems-to-be-thrown-repeatedly-when-debugging)) but I've the same issue in release.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably reusing the same DbContext instance after the delete exception is thrown. If SaveChanges() fails, the changes are still being tracked by the DbContext.ChangeTracker. You have to create a new DbContext instance or clear the change tracker.

Comment: Or Rollback the changes made to your context

Comment: I've chosen the 2d option and wrote a rollback method (cf. [Undo changes in entity framework entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466677/undo-changes-in-entity-framework-entities)). Thanks, I didn't realize I would have to clear entity after handling the exception.